# java.util.List com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.VideoInfo.variants' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, twitter

I'm trying to build a twitter image, video, and gif downloader app on Android Studio.
*I'm able to download video and gif files but I'm unable to download images. It gives me an error when I put Twitter image URL in Edittext:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
> 'java.util.List
> com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.VideoInfo.variants' on a null
> object reference

*The error in code : `url = result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).videoInfo.variants.get(i).url;` How can I achieve to download images from Twitter URL?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.esafirm.rxdownloader.RxDownloader;
import com.shid.twittervideo.R;
import com.shid.twittervideo.util.Constant;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.DefaultLogger;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.StatusesService;

import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import retrofit2.Call;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_download, btn_paste;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private TextView txt_url;
    private ClipboardManager clipboardManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUI();
        btnClick();
        checkPermission();
        setTwitterConfig();

    }

    public void setTwitterConfig() {

        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(Constant.TWITTER_KEY, Constant.TWITTER_SECRET))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void setUI() {
        btn_download = findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
        txt_url = findViewById(R.id.txt_tweet_url);
        btn_paste = findViewById(R.id.btn_paste);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching video....");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        txt_url.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (txt_url.getRight() - txt_url.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        // your action here
                        txt_url.setText("");

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void btnClick() {
        btn_paste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                try {
                    CharSequence textToPaste = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();
                    txt_url.setText(textToPaste);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        btn_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fname;

                //Check if the tweet url field has text containing twitter.com/...
                if (txt_url.getText().length() > 0 && txt_url.getText().toString().contains("twitter.com/")) {

                    Long id = getTweetId(txt_url.getText().toString());
                    fname = String.valueOf(id);

                    //Call method to get tweet
                    if (id != null) {
                        getTweet(id, fname);
                    } else {
                        alertNoUrl();
                    }
                } else{
                    alertNoUrl();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkPermission() {
        //If we don't have permission we prompt the user
        if (!storageAllowed()) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Constant.PERMISSION_STRORAGE, Constant.REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    private void getTweet(Long id, String fname) {
        progressDialog.show();

        TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
        Call<Tweet> tweetCall = statusesService.show(id, null, null, null);
        tweetCall.enqueue(new Callback<Tweet>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {

                Log.d("MartianDeveloper", ""+result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type);

                //Check if media is present
                if (result.data.extendedEntities == null && result.data.entities.media == null) {
                    alertNoMedia();
                } else if (result.data.extendedEntities != null) {
                    if (!(result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("video") &&
                            !(result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("animated_gif") && !(result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("photo")) {
                        alertNoVideo();
                    } else {
                        String filename = fname;
                        String url;

                        //Set filename to gif or mp4
                        if ((result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("video") ||
                                (result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("animated_gif")) {
                            filename = filename + ".mp4";
                            Log.d("TAG", "filenme for video is " + filename);

                        }else if ((result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).type).equals("photo")){
                            filename = filename + ".jpg";
                        }

                        int i = 0;
                        url = result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).videoInfo.variants.get(i).url;

                        Log.d("TAG", "url is " + url);

                        while (!url.contains(".mp4")) {
                            try {
                                if (result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).videoInfo.variants.get(i) != null) {
                                    url = result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).videoInfo.variants.get(i).url;
                                    Log.d("TAG", "url2 is " + url);
                                    i += 1;
                                }
                            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                                downloadVideo(url, filename);
                            }
                        }

                        downloadVideo(url, filename);
                    }
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request failed, check your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void downloadVideo(String url, String filename) {

        //Check if External Storage permission js allowed
        if (!storageAllowed()) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Constant.PERMISSION_STRORAGE, Constant.REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kindly grant the request and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            RxDownloader rxDownloader = new RxDownloader(MainActivity.this);
            rxDownloader.download(url, filename, "video/*", true)
                    .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started: Check Notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }


    private void alertNoVideo() {
        progressDialog.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this, "URL entered do not contain any video or gif", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void alertNoMedia() {
        progressDialog.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this, "The link entered do not contain any media", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private Long getTweetId(String s) {
        Log.d("TAG", "link is :" + s);

        try {
            String[] split = s.split("\\/");
            String id = split[5].split("\\?")[0];
            return Long.parseLong(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "getTweetId: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            alertNoUrl();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void alertNoUrl() {

        Toast.makeText(this,getResources().getString(R.string.toast_url) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    //Method that checks the permission depending on the version of the phone
    private boolean storageAllowed() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            return permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put this code to retrieve the image `result.data.extendedEntities.media.get(0).mediaUrl`

Comment: Change the 0 to get multiple images